# The failure of Arzela-Ascoli over non-archimedean fields

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, number-theory, arzela-ascoli, arithmetic-dynamics

Let $K$ be a complete, algebraically closed non-archimedean field.
The Arzela-Ascoli theorem fails over such a field $K$.

I found an example on a book, but not quite get it.
Here is an example :

$\color{blue}{Let\,\,\, \{x_n\} \,\,be \,\,a\,\, sequence \,\,of\,\, points\,\, in\,\, \mathbb{P}^1(K)\,\, with\,\, no\,\, accumulation\,\, points.\,\, Thus\,\, the\,\, family\,\, of\,\, constant\,\, functions\,\, \{x_n: n\geq 0\}\,\, is\,\, equicontinuous\,\, but \,\,not\,\, normal\,\, on\,\, any\,\, open\,\, subset\,\, U\subseteq \mathbb{P}^1(K).}$

It would be good if someone could explain this to me.

By any chance, is it possible to write such sequence $\{x_n\}\subset\mathbb{P}^1(K)$ concretely?

So the normality and equicontinuity of family of functions cannot be used interchangeably over non-archimedean field, right?

Comment: Hi, do you mind to share the title and author of the book? Thanks

Comment: @Chilote It's Dynamics in One Non-Archimedean Variable by Robert Benedetto.

Comment: Anything unclear

Answer (score 1):

We need that $K$ has an infinite residue field, it doesn't work with $K=\Bbb{Q}_p$.

(For $p\ne 2$) with $K= \Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{2^\infty})$ (well its completion in fact) take $$x_n=[\zeta_{2^n}:1]$$
$$d(x_n,x_m)=\inf_j |x_n(j)-x_m(j)|_p=1$$

Comment: Thanks! How does this field $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{2^{\infty}})$ looks like? I'm probably not quite sure what you are trying to tell me. Sorry about that.

Comment: The infinite algebraic extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ obtained by adjoining  all $2^n$-th roots of unity. Its ring of integers has an infinite residue field. This is the necessary and sufficient condition for the completion of $O_K$ not being compact (no need that $K$ is algebraically closed).